# Do you have to vent the space between wall and drywall for a finished basement?

Tags: walls

The ceiling in my furnace room is open.
I have been chasing the source of the bad smell in my basement for about a year when I finally realized that the smell is coming out of that room. Here is a quick description of the situation:

-ceiling in the furnace room is not finished. Batt insulation was stuffed between joists to close the openings toward the finished ceiling of the adjacent rooms
-there is an opening that used to connect an old furnace to the chimney. For some reasons this was not closed and the layers of insulation (foam, batt and plastic barrier) can be seen through this
-the insulation was broken in two smaller areas where the rails that take the fan out of the furnace hit the wall

The smell is more like the smell of the air trapped for a long time in a basement that has just batt insulation (no drywall or vapor barrier)

I am not sure what I should do about these. Is it a good idea to actually try to use these openings and this room to try to ventilate the space between the basement walls and the insulation by let's say installing a fan and venting out the air that I evacuate from this space ? I guess that air from the upper floor will be sucked in through the top floor and somehow some form of ventilation will occur ...
Of course with these I am also hoping to eliminate the smell from that room too
Is there a standard practice for situations like this?

Comment: Generally it doesn't need to be vented, but you may need to allow for possible water infiltration and drainage.